# Excel: formula to display the current balance

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I set up a spreadsheet to keep the balance of various accounts. Column O is the expense amount. O242 is an expense for Colmn T. So, T242 is 170 less than T241.

What should be shown in row 401 of column Q, S, T, X, and Y is the current balance of each account. The formula in row 401 looks for the last non-zero value in the column. So, Q401 shows Q245, S401 S240, T401 T244, Y401 Y243. They look fine except column X.

O246 is an expense for column X. The previous balance of column X is 3000. Once 3000 is spent, X246 is 0, which is the current balance of X. Because the formula looks for the LAST NON-ZERO value, X246 is ignored and X401 displays X225. This is not the correct result. It should display 0.

I can think of a VBA solution in which a variable is set up to keep the balance of each account. However, I'm looking for a non-VBA answer. Possible?

The formula in X401 is this:

```
=IF(SUM(INDIRECT("X5:X"&AGGREGATE(14,7,(ROW(X5:X400))/SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(X5,ROW(X5:X400)-ROW(X5),0)),1)))=0,0,LOOKUP(2,1/INDIRECT("X5:X" & AGGREGATE(14,7,(ROW(X5:X400))/SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(X5,ROW(X5:X400)-ROW(X5),0)),1) ),INDIRECT("X5:X" & AGGREGATE(14,7,(ROW(X5:X400))/SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(X5,ROW(X5:X400)-ROW(X5),0)),1) )))
```

[image]

Comment: What makes that O246 is an expense for column X. What's the logic behind that.

Comment: Columns K to M are incomes, local currency, US dollar, and bank transactions; columns N to P are similar to K to M except they are expenses. Columns A to J are info about date, account, payee, memo, etc. Cells (rows 5 - 400) in column Q and down contain formula so each column (account) picks up the transactions that are pertain to it and leaves a zero (no transaction) in the cell if irrelevent. The sheet had been working for more than six months. Unfortunately, I just found out today zero can mean no transaction or balance being zero, which causes the problem described above.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following `LOOKUP` formula, e.g. for column `Q` enter the following into cell `Q401`:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(Q1:Q400<>""),Q1:Q400)
```

Comment: I have modified the post to add in the formula in X401. There is a good chance that the formula could be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

For `X401` cell use following formula. Tim Biegeleisen shows to get last value of a column. You jaust need to minus last value of `O Column` from last value of `X Column`.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(X1:X400<>""),X1:X400)-LOOKUP(2,1/(O1:O400<>""),O1:O400)
```

Comment: I have modified the post to add in the formula in X401. There is a good chance that the formula could be simplified.